# Turning a dataframe into a graph in R

Tags: r, graph

Let's assume I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
 row    id    event    actor     time
 1      1     push     dude      1
 2      1     comment  guy       2   
 3      1     comment  guy       3
 4      2     request  person    1
 5      2     comment  person    2
 6      2     merge    dude      2
 7      3     comment  guy       3
 8      3     comment  dude      4
 9      3     reject   person    5
```

Now, assume that I want to turn this into a graph (edge list), using the following rule: a directed edge is created from an actor on row n to the actor on row n+1, if they share the same id. E.g.

- `dude -> guy` (for id 1).
- but not `guy -> person` (while guy appears on row 3, and person on row 4, they have different ids).

Hence, I would end up with a graph that looks like this

```
from     to        time
dude     guy       1-2
guy      guy       2-3   
person   person    1-2
person   dude      2
guy      dude      3-4
dude     person    4-5
```

How would I start to approach this problem in R code? I'm lost at even how I would start doing this. This would be useful, because it would help to construct social networks based on event workflow data.

In terms of pseudocode I think it would be something like this:

```
for each rows n and n+1
   if row n "id" = row n+1 "id"
     store "actor" from row n in column "from"
     store "actor" from row n+1 in column "to"
     store "time" from row n in column "time"
     unless "time" row n = "time" row n+1 
       append "time" from row n+1 in column "time"
   else
     move to next row
end
```

Comment: The `igraph` package may help you. It has a data structure for graphs, along with several ways of converting between it and other formats.

Comment: @Frank how would you use the `igraph` package in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could have a look at the documentation. I think that package is the standard way of doing graph stuff in R.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not helpful. The `igraph`, `sna`, or `network` packages would be useful in analyzing the graph once the data is in the form of an edgelist. However, this is more of a text processing/data manipulation problem that occurs prior to loading the data into a specific graph package.

Comment: Oh I see. So two people can do something at the same time and one person can be linked to him/herself, but the latter only occurs if they're there for multiple periods. Hrm...

Comment: Yes. In most graph packages it is easy to retain or delete "self-loops", so this information might as well be retained. The person only becomes linked to himself if he executes two actions sequentially within the same "id" (workflow). Having the same "id" indicates being part of the same workflow (e.g. as in working on the same pull request on Github).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick way to do this. I am not sure how robust it would be.

```
library(plyr)
dat2 <- ddply(dat, .(id), function(d){
  data.frame(
    event = d$event[-1],
    from = d$actor[-NROW(d)],
    to = d$actor[-1],
    time = paste(d$time[-NROW(d)], d$time[-1], sep = "-")
  )
})
```

Comment: +1. Is there a quick way to do the final string processing step? (See the OP's desired result.) Mine is very clunky.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a data.table way:

```
# make an edge list (pairs of nodes) with attributes
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
gdt <- DT[,{
  nodes <- actor # not unique(actor), strangely
  list(
    n1=head(nodes,-1),
    n2=tail(nodes,-1),
    t1=head(time,-1),
    t2=tail(time,-1)
)},by=id]
# do annoying string processing
gdt[,
  time:=do.call(paste,c(unique(c(t1,t2)),list(sep='-'))),
,by=1:nrow(gdt)][,
c('id','t1','t2'):=NULL
]
```

which gives

```
       n1     n2 time
1:   dude    guy  1-2
2:    guy    guy  2-3
3: person person  1-2
4: person   dude    2
5:    guy   dude  3-4
6:   dude person  4-5
```

And then make a graph

```
require(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(gdt)
```

Comment: I think it's better to just keep t1 and t2 as attributes. The conversion to a string with a dash can be saved for printing...